# CWnd::WindowProc - override function

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm develop a Plugin for the application, and I need to insert a menu, as an extension. The problem is that the message is not processed. I got a pointer to the window procedure, but how to use the function `CWnd::WindowProc` have no idea. I tried to override the function `CWnd::WindowProc`, but it does not work:

```
LRESULT Plugin::WindowProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == ID_EXPCATXML)
        {
            Plugin::OnExportCatalogXML();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return CWnd::WindowProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Any ideas are welcome, thanks

Comment: _"... but it does not work ..."_ Elaborate, what specifically _doesn't work_ in your question please! Did you get compilation errors (post verbatim please), runtime exceptions or unexpected results? What did you observe when stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: The [repository](https://github.com/INTITY/KDE/blob/master/src/KDE/Plugin.cpp) on GitHub

Comment: I don't care about your git repo. Provide a self contained [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please!

Comment: I need to process the message inserted into the menu. If you can redefine the function `CWnd::WindowProc` for this purpose, but I do not understand the principle of how to do it.

Comment: When the application starts, loaded DLL, which has a function InsertMenu. The menu is displayed, but not executed handler `OnExportCatalogXML`. If insert menu for window procedure processed by the application, I believe that it is necessary to override `WindowProc` function or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found by using the special function of [CWnd::SubclassWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892.aspx) to override subclass the application window:

```
bool Plugin::OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    SessionId = app->StartSessionFromCallParams(&CallParamBlock);
    if (SessionId != 0)
    {
        m_pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("#32770"), _T("MobiScript"));
        HWND hWnd = m_pWnd->m_hWnd;

        if (m_pWnd != NULL)
        {
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(6);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_EXPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML\tCtrl+E"));
            }
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(7);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_IMPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML\tCtrl+I"));
            }
        }

        plugin.SubclassWindow(hWnd);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}
```